# Ambigious field on joining of CI 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have many branches and under one branch there are multiple cars.

So I need to join branch table with the car table .

My following code outputs an error like, "Column 'branch_id' in field list is ambiguous"

```
 $this->db->join("company","branch.company_id=company.company_id");
 $this->db->join("cars","branch.branch_id = cars.branch_id");
```

I have not used repeat of branch_id .

Any suggestion ?

Thank you.

Comment: It shows field list. This means ambiguity is in `SELECT` statement. Please post your `SELECT` statement too.

Comment: Pls share the executed sql code, that will give us a hint. My guess is that in the select list CI may not have applied any prefix.

Comment: Yes I got ,One prefix is missing

Comment: Kindly post the full query as everyone asked.. So that we can get a idea about it

Comment: But my joining is not working for multiple cars @Shadow

Comment: Only if you're sure that you want to JOIN the same table twice.... then for each join the alias for the table will have to be different. For example: `SELECT c1.car_name, c2.car_name, ...., .... FROM branch INNER JOIN company ON branch.company_id = company.company_id INNER JOIN cars c1 ON branch.branch_id = c1.branch_id INNER JOIN cars c2 ON branch.branch_id = c2.branch_id `